# Generar función que devuelva string formado por tres subcadenas

Tags: c++

Quería crear una función que devuelva un string formado por tres subcadenas para, más tarde, añadirlo a una cadena general con más elementos. 
Mi problema está en que no devuelve o no se consigue mostrar en la cadena general (función aCadena()).

Son tres funciones: **string generarTejuelo()** Devuelve el tejuelo de un libro. El tejuelo de un libro cumple el siguiente formato:
xxxxxx-yyyyy-zzz
Donde:
xxxxxx son los 6 primeros caracteres del título
yyyyy son los 5 primeros caracteres del autor
zzz: son los 3 primeros caracteres del género.
El usuario no puede modificar el tejuelo, los constructores
de Libro se encargan de asignar el tejuelo de un libro en el
momento de su creación.

**void setTejuelo()** Asigna el tejuelo de un libro. Esta función se encarga de
generar el tejuelo de un libro y asignarla a la variable
tejuelo.

**string aCadena()** Devuelve concatenados los datos de un libro con el
siguiente formato:
TÍTULO. AUTOR. (género). xx pags. [tejuelo]

Libro.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#ifndef LIBRO_H_
#define LIBRO_H_

using namespace std;

class Libro {

public:
    Libro();
    Libro (string t, string au, string gen, int num);
    Libro(string lineafich);

    virtual ~Libro();

    string  generarTejuelo();
    void setTejuelo();

    string getTitulo();
    void setTitulo(string titulo);

    string getAutor();
    void setAutor(string autor);

    string getGenero();
    void setGenero(string genero);

    int getNumPaginas();
    void setNumPaginas(int numPaginas);

    string aCadena();
    string formatoFichero();

    bool tieneDatos();
    Libro copiarLibro();

private:
    string titulo;
    string autor;
    string  genero;
    string tejuelo;
    int numPaginas;
};

#endif /* LIBRO_H_ */
```

Libro.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Libro.h"

using namespace std;

Libro::~Libro() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

Libro::Libro() {
    titulo = "";
    autor = "";
    genero = "";
    tejuelo = "";
    numPaginas = 0;
}

Libro::Libro(string t, string au, string gen, int num) {
    titulo = t;
    autor = au;
    genero = gen;
    numPaginas = num;
}

Libro::Libro(string linea) {
    numPaginas = 0;
    string delimiter = ";";
   size_t pos = 0;
   string token;
   string datos[4+10];
   int i=0;
   while ((pos = linea.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
       token = linea.substr(0, pos);
       datos[i]=token;
       i++;
       linea.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
   }
   int n = atoi(datos[3].c_str());
    titulo = datos[0];
    genero = datos[2];
    autor = datos[1];
    numPaginas = n;
}

string Libro::getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
void Libro::setTitulo(string t) {
    titulo = t;
}
string Libro::getAutor() {
    return autor;
}
void Libro::setAutor(string au) {
    autor = au;
}
string Libro::getGenero() {
    return genero;
}
void Libro::setGenero(string gen){
    genero=gen;
}
int Libro:: getNumPaginas(){
    return numPaginas;
}

void Libro:: setNumPaginas(int num){
    numPaginas = num;
}
string  Libro:: generarTejuelo(){
    string titulo, autor, genero, tej;
    string subcadena1(titulo,0,5);
    string subcadena2(autor,0,4);
    string subcadena3(genero,0,2);
    tej = subcadena1 + "-" + subcadena2 + "-" + subcadena3;
    return tej;
}
void Libro:: setTejuelo(){
    tejuelo = generarTejuelo();
}
bool Libro:: tieneDatos(){
    bool resul;
    if (titulo != "" && autor != "")
            resul = true;
        else resul = false;
    return resul;
}
string Libro:: aCadena(){
    string cadena;
    stringstream convertirPags;
    convertirPags << numPaginas;
    string f = convertirPags.str();

    cadena = titulo + "." + autor + ".(" + genero + "). " + f + " pags. [" + tejuelo +"]" ;
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: No acabo de entender cuál es la pregunta.

Comment: Quería saber cuál es el problema al utilizar las funciones generarTejuelo(), setTejuelo() y aCadena(). En teoría en el código principal se hace la llamada a aCadena() y genera una cadena con titulo, autor, genero y numero de páginas pero no imprime el tejuelo.

Comment: ¿Qué datos entras en el programa y qué salida obtienes exáctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string Libro:: aCadena(){
    string cadena;
    stringstream convertirPags;
    convertirPags << numPaginas;
    string f = convertirPags.str();

    cadena = titulo + "." + autor + ".(" + genero + "). " + f + " pags. [" + tejuelo +"]" ;
    return cadena;
}
```

`tejuelo` es una variable propia de `Libro`. ¿En qué momento actualizas el valor de dicha variable?

Quizás lo más recomendable, dado el caracter dinámico de `tejuelo`, que se ve modificado al cambiar el título, el autor o el género, llamar directamente a la función `generarTejuelo` y eliminar la variable miembro `tejuelo`.

```
string Libro:: aCadena(){
    stringstream convertirPags;
    convertirPags << numPaginas;
    string f = convertirPags.str();

    return titulo + "." + autor + ".(" + genero + "). " + f + " pags. [" + generarTejuelo() +"]" ;
}
```

La otra alternativa es actualizar el valor de la variable `tejuelo` cada vez que se modifica el título, el autor o el género:

```
void Libro::setTitulo(string t) {
    titulo = t;
    tejuelo = generarTejuelo();
}
```

Por otro lado, la función `generarTejuelo` tiene sus propios problemas:

```
string  Libro:: generarTejuelo(){
    string titulo, autor, genero, tej;
    string subcadena1(titulo,0,5);
    string subcadena2(autor,0,4);
    string subcadena3(genero,0,2);
    tej = subcadena1 + "-" + subcadena2 + "-" + subcadena3;
    return tej;
}
```

Para generar la cadena `tej` estás haciendo uso de variables locales: `titulo`, `autor` y `genero` en vez de las variables miembro con mismo nombre. La solución es tan sencilla como eliminar las variables locales:

```
string  Libro:: generarTejuelo(){
    string subcadena1(titulo,0,5);
    string subcadena2(autor,0,4);
    string subcadena3(genero,0,2);
    return subcadena1 + "-" + subcadena2 + "-" + subcadena3;
}
```

Un saludo